# Typo3 adjust processed path for processed images programmatically

Tags: image-processing, storage, typo3, directory

I'm looking for a solution to generate the processed files for one database in an explicitly via uid defined folder. F.e.:

```
fileadmin/_processed/<uid>/allProcessedFilesHere
```

The generation of the files happens via the following code at the moment and I am not able to figure out how to adjust the config array to pass different storage.

```
$settings['additionalParameters'] = '-quality 80';
$settings['width'] = $imageSettings["width"];
$settings['height'] = $imageSettings["height"];
$processedImage = $file->process(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ProcessedFile::CONTEXT_IMAGECROPSCALEMASK, $settings);
```

So I am looking for something similar to the following, where $uid is just the id of the entry that images shall get processed:

```
$storageRepository = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Resource\\StorageRepository');
$uidForStorageForDBEntry = getStorageUidForDBObject($uid);
$identifiedStorage = $storageRepository->findByUid($uidForStorageForDBEntry);
$settings['storage'] = $identifiedStorage->getUid()
```

To create one storage per uid seems not be the way to do it right, but I can't figure out another approach at the moment. As there are hundreds of objects with images in many different formats, I don't want to use a _processed folder with 100k image entries inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are integrating the functionality to bind the processed folder to a storage element into the Typo3 Core. It should work in Version 7 LTS.

Comment: Thanks. Frans Saris wrote the same in the typo3 dev list.